# Will wolves attack Ocelots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Will wolves attack and kill ocelots in Minecraft? I know they kill sheep. I just don't want my cats being eaten.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf):

> All wolves will appear to 'scare' an ocelot, but it's actually the normal "coming too close" behavior they display with players. Tamed wolves do not appear to scare, or fight with, tamed ocelots (cats).

Answer (score 0):

Untamed wolves will only attack sheep (and you if you attack them) and tamed wolves will attack any mob you attack or any mob that attacks you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually whoever said untamed wolves only attack sheep is wrong. Untamed wolves will attack sheep, but they will also attack rabbits, skeletons, and players who attack them. They can also attack tamed wolves sometimes because if you hit an untamed wolf your tamed wolves will attack it, causing the untamed wolf to fight back. Tamed wolves will attack a skeleton upon noticing it's presence if the skeleton is nearby. I also noticed if you hit a silverfish while you have tamed wolves your wolves will attack, but if untamed wolves are near enough where they notice a tamed wolf attacked by silverfish then the untamed wolves will jump in to help the tamed wolves defeat the silverfish.

Answer (score -2):

I think they kill baby ocelots because i literally saw my baby wolf kill my baby ocelots :(

Comment: You think or you know?